# Typescript not throwing an error on poor generic use as I think it should

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I've stumbled upon some Typescript behavior that I don't understand. See the short code example:

```js
interface ComponentProps<T> {
  oldObject: T
}

function Component<T>({ oldObject }: ComponentProps<T>) {
  const newObject = {
    ...oldObject
  }
  return <div>hi</div>
}


// component call in some other component that shows no TS errors
return <Component<number> oldObject={5} />
```

In this example, it seems like T isn't being treated appropriately as a generic that essentially has type `any`. I can pass `number` and it will not throw any errors, even though spreading a number in `newObject` shouldn't work. However, if I remove the generic and just type `oldObject` as a number, then it throws and error saying that only objects and strings are spreadable, as it should.

I understand that I can use a constraint to narrow down allowable types for T, but shouldn't typescript say that? Seems to me that not throwing an error when attempting to spread an `any` should show an error.

Is there a setting that I need to enable to see this behavior? How can I use generics such that I don't lose TS errors?

Comment: Add constraints accordingly. For example, if you want to spread it, you may want to add an `object` constraint.

Comment: This is a known issue; see [microsoft/TypeScript#38469](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38469).  For now the best advice is to use `T extends object` and maybe give that issue a  to let them know people care about it.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this answers it. After testing this across different environments/tsconfigs I figured this was probably flying under the radar but glad there's an issue already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#38469](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38469).  As you found, the compiler will happily let you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) a value of [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) into an object literal, even if that generic type could be a non-object primitive.  There's no compiler option to change this.

The GitHub issue has been open a long time without much engagement, so I doubt it will be addressed anytime soon, if ever.  If you want to see something happen it wouldn't hurt for you to give it a .  It probably wouldn't help much either, but it wouldn't hurt.

So, until and unless it gets addressed, your best way forward is to work around it and explicitly [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) relevant generic type parameters to [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type).  This will at least make it so that you are protecting yourself from this in your own code, even if the problem still exists in general.